# Relevant tests for The Service Locator Pattern In C#

Tags: c#, nunit, service-locator

I've used this Service Locator Pattern in my Application and implemented as a Singleton:

[Service Locator Pattern](http://stefanoricciardi.com/2009/09/25/service-locator-pattern-in-csharpa-simple-example/)

And now I want test it .So far I've written a test verifying that my class is a Singleton. I've also written this test:

```
 [Test]
 [ExpectedException(typeof(ApplicationException))]
 public void GetService_Throws_Exception_When_Invalid_Key_Is_Provided()
 {
     locator.GetService<IRandomService>();
 }
```

But I don't really like the last test since I'm never going to use the IRandomService. So I'm looking for a nicer way to test that the `GetService<T>` throws an exception. Also I like to know if there is any other relevants tests I could write for this class.

I'm using the latest version of NUnit.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Some things:

- A test to verify the class is a singleton? The singleton pattern will ensure that attempting to treat a singleton as an instance class won't even compile. If you have not written your service locator something like the following, it's wrong:

The Singleton Pattern in C#:

```
public class MySingleton()
{
    //Could also be a readonly field, or private with a GetInstance method
    public static MySingleton Instance {get; private set;}
    static MySingleton()
    {
        Instance = new MySingleton();
    }
    private MySingleton() { ... }
} 

...

//in external code
var mySingletonInstanceRef = MySingleTon.Instance; //right
var mySingletonInstanceRef = new MySingleton(); //does not compile

//EDIT: The thread-safe lazy-loaded singleton
 public class MySingleton()
{
    //static fields with initializers are initialized on first reference, so this behaves lazily
    public static readonly MySingleton instance = new MySingleton();
    //instead of the below you could make the field public, or have a GetInstance() method
    public static MySingleton Instance {get{return instance;}

    private MySingleton() { ... }
}
```

- The service locator is an anti-pattern. It sounds great, but it doesn't really solve the problems that it was created to solve. The chief problem is that it tightly couples you to the service locator; if the locator changes, every class that uses it changes. By contrast, Dependency Injection can be done without a fancy framework; you just make sure any complex, expensive, reusable, etc. object is passed in to the object that needs it via its constructor. DI/IoC frameworks just streamline this process by ensuring that all known dependencies of a required object are provided, even if an object in the graph can't know about dependencies of its children.
- You have already developed the class. The spirit of TDD/BDD is that you write tests that will prove that code you haven't yet written will be correct. I'm not saying writing tests now wouldn't serve a purpose, but a failing test requires the object be opened up and fixed, and if the code is already integrated you could break other things.
- Unit tests make heavy use of constructs that will never see production. Mocks, stubs, proxies and other "test helpers" exist to isolate the object under test from the environment into which it is normally integrated, guaranteeing that if the inputs are A, B, and C, the object under test will do X, regardless of whether what it normally hooks into will give it A, B, and C. Therefore, don't worry about creating simple constructs like a skeleton interface that you wouldn't use in production; as long as it is a good representation of the input you would expect in the test case, it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

> But I don't really like the last test since I'm never going to use the `IRandomService`.

But that's kind of the point. You wire up your locator in the test setup method (arrange), and then you lookup a key that was not wired up (act), then you check that an exception was thrown (assert). You don't need to use types you're actually going to use, you just want to get some confidence that your method is working.

> Also I like to know if there is any other relevants tests I could write for this class.

Well, I'm going to answer a different question here.

> Is the service locator pattern evil?

Yes, it is pure evil.

It defeats the purpose of dependency injection because it doesn't make dependencies explicit (any class can pull anything out of the service locator). Moreover, it makes your all of your components dependent on this one class.

It makes maintenance an unbelievable nightmare because now you have this one component that is just spread all over your codebase. You have become tightly coupled to this one class.

Further, testing is a nightmare. Let's say you have

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo() { // }
    public string Bar() { // }
}
```

and you want to test `Foo.Bar`.

```
public void BarDoesSomething() {
    var foo = new Foo();
    Assert.Equal("Something", foo.Bar());
}
```

and you run your test and you get an exception

```
ServiceLocator could not resolve component Frob.
```

What? Oh that's because your constructor looks like this:

```
public Foo() {
    this.frob = ServiceLocator.GetService<Frob>();
}
```

And on and on.

avoid, Avoid, AVOID.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your question.  Are you dissatisfied with requesting a type that you'll never use in production?  Are you dissatisfied with using the service locator in a fashion that is not indicative of production code?  The test itself looks ok to me -- you're requesting something that doesn't exist and proving that the expected behaviour occurs.  For a unit test, such a thing is perfectly reasonable to do.

One thing we did when using a dependency injection container was to separate our application wiring phase into modules, then we'd try and resolve the root type in an integration test to ensure that the app could be wired up.  If the wiring test failed, it was a good sign that the app wasn't working (though it didn't prove that the app worked, either).  It'd be tricker to do this sort of thing when using a service locator.

I agree 100% with Jason, too -- service locators seem like a good idea, but quickly turn nasty.  They 'pull' (types using the service locator instance must be coupled to it), whereas Dependency Injection containers 'push' (the vast majority of the application is DI agnostic, so the code is far less brittle and more re-usable).

A couple of other things:

1. `[ExpectedException]` is deprecated.
   use Assert.Throws
   instead
2. `ApplicationException` is
   also deprecated.

Comment: I'm a newbie to testing and all theese patterns. so basically I'm just practicing. What kind of exception should I use instead of applicationException?

Comment: @KeithS : Let me see if I got you right..testing that a class is restricted to one live instance is worthless?

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to use DI container..pretend I had a couple of viewmodels using this servicelocator. would it a better approach to do something like :newDummyViewModel(IDummyService Service) ?